# 2 jQuery plugins competing for the same #id

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have smooth-scroll *jQuery* code that is completing with my bootstrap carousel jQuery code for the targeted #id.

This is the smooth scroll code:

```
$('[href^=#]').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var div = $(this).attr('href');
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(div).position().top
  }, "slow");
});
```

This code unfortunately competes with my bootstrap carousel *jQuery* code over the `#myCarousel` id. So whenever I click on the carousel left/right buttons the smooth-scroll jQuery will take effect and smooth-scroll my webpage, which I do not want.

This is the *html* for the carousel part:

```
<div id="myCarousel">

  <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <img src="img/left.png"></a>
  <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <img src="img/right.png"></a>
```

How can I isolate the effects of the smooth-scroll from the carousel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `not()`

```
$('[href^=#]').not('#myCarousel a').click....
```